# Navigate to main fragment from viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have created navigation drawer in MainActvity and Main
Fragment.
I want to navigate to viewpager from MainFragment by clicking on gridview.
here is the code of gridview:

```
                android.support.v4.app.Fragment fv;

                    case 4:
                             fv=new Events();
                             android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransactio fts=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                             fts.replace(R.id.fragment_container,fv,"visible_fragment");
                             fts.addToBackStack(null);
                             fts.commit();
                    break;
```

My Events.java is viewpager which is fragment android.support.v4.app.Fragment.

And from viewpager i cannot navigate to MainFragment,
When i click to main fragment the whole content is display inside viewpager.
I have implemented onBackpressed in MainActivity as follow:

```
      @Override
     public void onBackPressed() {
      if(getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() != 0) {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
            }
         }
```

I am not able to goto viewpager fragment from main fragment and i cannot goto main fragment from view pager.
With navigation drawer  i can goto viewpager fragment.

Comment: You're on 3rd `Fragment` of `ViewPager` and you wanna move to 1st `Fragment` back?

Comment: no from 1st fragment

Comment: @maulik what exactly you want to do.? can you explain clear.

Comment: i have two fragment inside view pager and from 1st fragment i want to goto main fragment,but onbackpress the content of main fragment is displayed inside  viewpager

Comment: then call `FragmentTransaction` again.

Comment: but we cannot override onBackpress in viewpager fragment.

Comment: where i can write can you please give me a hint

Comment: @maulik you have two fragment in viewpager and in one fragment  you have grid view .on that item click you want to open viewpager other fragment?

Comment: Main fragment contain viewpager .

Comment: Viewpager contain two fragment named upcoming events and completed events

Comment: I want to goto viewpager from main fragment

Comment: and iwant to goto main fragment from viewpager on backpress,but the main fragment content is displaying inside viewpager

Comment: @maulik you told you have view pager inside main fragment .now on back press you want to go main fragment so its same fragment from which you  press backpress

Comment: @maulik its confusing dear. you  should give proper explanation then anyone help you.

Comment: Main fragment contains gridview.

Comment: And viewpager contains two fragments named upcoming events and completed events